# Uniform convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Discuss the uniform convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$$ for real values of $x$.

Let $f(x)$ denote the given series. Then $f(0)=0+0+\ldots = 0$, and $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all real $x$. Also, $$f(1) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(1+n)} =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = 1.$$ For any $x$ we can write $$\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)} = \frac{x}{n}-\frac{x^3}{1+nx^2},$$ so $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{n}-\frac{x^3}{1+nx^2}\right).$$ How can we check which values of $x$ this sum converges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $$n(1+nx^2) \ge 2n \sqrt{n}|x|.$$

Comment: I see, so the series (when $x>0$) is bounded from above by $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$, which converges! And since $f(-x)=-f(x)$, the series converges for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, but not only for positive $x$'s. It converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Indeed, since each term of $f(-x)$ is just the negative of the corresponding term in $f(x)$. Now onto uniform convergence...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Comment: That kills it immediately, thanks!

Comment: @njguliyev Sorry to bother you about an old question, but this sort of hint frustrates me quite a bit. Where did that estimate come from? Is there a more directly clear way to show uniform convergence of the sum? Is this a standard result? It seems to come from nowhere!

Comment: @TheCount I think the hint follows from the AM-GM inequality.